# Is there such a thing as "completeness" theory for UI layout managers?

Tags: ui

Given the often wide variety of layout managers available on any particular UI platform, I was wondering if there is something akin to a "theory of layout completeness" that can be used to describe them. Can we reason about all the possible layouts that can be made using, say, flexbox?

An example where such information would be useful would be in choosing which layout manager to use. If we know that managers B and C are strict subsets of A, then we can always safely use A. I'm not arguing that this is always a good idea: a manager where we layout each element manually based on window size, state, etc will be able to produce any layout in the universal set.

Comment: This is a fascinating question. While I don't think it's opinion based, it is unsuitable for this site: answering the question would likely require substantial novel research. In reality, I would expect that layout techniques have somewhat orthogonal capabilities and don't form a hierarchy. It would also often be desirable to use the simplest API, not the most powerful one.